# Create a second sequence, same object

Tags: python, odoo

Purchase order already have a sequence, my first question  is:

How can I create a second sequence ?

How can I restrict this sequence only for a particular partner ?

This is my code I use, but  obviously is overriding for the first sequence.

```
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'purchase.order'
_name = 'purchase.order'

def create(self, cr, uid,vals, context={}):
    vals['bic_code'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'purchase.order')
    res = super(purchase_order, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)
    return res

def copy(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
    default.update({
    'bic_code': self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'purchase.order')
    })
    return super(porchase_order, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context)



_columns = {
    'bic_code': fields.char('Referencia Bic', size=64, readonly=True),
    }

_defaults = {
        'bic_code': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'purchase.order'),
        }
```

purchase_order()

XML sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <record model="ir.sequence.type" id="seq_type_purchase_bic">
        <field name="name">number_bic_sequence</field>
        <field name="code">purchase.order.bic1</field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.sequence" id="seq_purchase_bic">
        <field name="name">number_bic_sequence</field>
        <field name="code">purchase.order.bic1</field>
        <field name="prefix">10670-</field>
        <field name="padding">5</field>
    </record>

</data>
```

XML view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<record id="view_bic_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">purchase.bic.order.form</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="/form/group/field[@name='date_order']" position="after">
        <field name="bic_code" />
    </xpath>
    </field>
</record>


</data>
```

Thank you very much for any help you can give me

Answer (score 0):

what you have done to create new sequence for purchase is ok.

to restrict particular sequence for particular partner is not any existing functionality in openerp, for this you have to done some customization in your module,

like in purchase order sequence generated when you create new purchase order, then overwrite the create method and add code here , check the partner if partner is belong to old sequence then generated sequence from old or belong to new then generate sequence from new one sequence

hope this help